# Slug name and id Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I try to make a slug attribute for my User model with his name and id in the same time, and to doing that i try to make a saved function in the EventServiceProvider, This function will be executed after save user, code :

```
User::saved(function($user){
             $user->slug = str_slug($user->name.' '.$user->id);
             $user->save();
         });
```

But i get a prolem that, the save inside the function make a recursive call for the parent saved function  and this make the result be like this

> SQLSTATE[22001]: String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for
>   column 'slug' at row 1 (SQL: update `candidats` set `f_name` = malek,
>   `l_name` = aa, `email` = a@ra.com, `password` =
>   $2y$10$LD2vRISLv8Bo9va/RarOGOF/7xlg4BjRirOglFw0LB2AEgZiN.B9O, `slug` =
>   malek-aa-10-10-10-10-10-10-10-10-10-10-10-10-10-10-10-10-10-10-10-10-10-10-10-10-10-10-10-10-10-10-10-10-10-10-10-10-10-10-10-10-10-10-10-10-10-10-10-10-10-10-10-10-10-10-10-10-10-10-10-10-10-10, `updated_at` = 2017-03-25 23:52:32, `created_at` = 2017-03-25
>   23:52:32, `id` = 10 where `id` = 10)

How i can ignore the saved function call inside ? I need same help to fix that , thanks.

Comment: Thank you for response, how can i use hook for this issue.

Comment: Check my answer. It's even more simpler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't call `save()` inside `saved` as the latter is generated by the former.

You should use a combination of `created` *and* `saving` to set your `slug` value correctly. `created` is called after the initial save and `id` will be available. Some basic logic inside `saving` will catch future updates if the `name` field is ever updated.

```
User::created(function($user) {
  $user->slug = str_slug($user->name . ' ' . $user->id);
  $user->save();
});

User::saving(function($user) {
  if ($user->exists && $user->isDirty('name')) {
    $user->slug = str_slug($user->name . ' ' . $user->id);
  }
});
```

The list of available events are [outlined in the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#events).

Comment: Thank you for response, i can't get the `$user->id` before the save , so it should be `saved`

Comment: You're not going to be able to call `save()` inside `saved`. What about the `created` event for the first case, then check for `dirty('name')` on `saving` and update the slug in that case.

Comment: The issue is adding the `$user->id` in the slug and i can't get the `user->id` from `create` or `saving` event , because this events are before save in DB

Comment: Can you please explain how the user is going to get the id of the model in the saving event?

Comment: i get this error
>Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::dirty()

Comment: Update your answer, the second solution seems correct. With the combination of  `created` and `saving`. So, remove  the `saving` event from the top.

Answer (score 0):

You may give it a try (not tested):

<strike>User::saved(function($user){
        $dispatcher = $user->getEventDispatcher();
        $user->unsetEventDispatcher();
        $user->slug = str_slug($user->name.' '.$user->id);
        $user->save();
        $user->setEventDispatcher($dispatcher);
    });</strike>

There is a better solution for this, just call the update method instead of save, for example:

```php
User::saved(function($user){
    // You may check if the name has been changed
    // Ex: if($user->isDirty('name')) { Update... }
    $user
    ->where('id', $user->id)
    ->update([
        'slug' => str_slug($user->name.' '.$user->id)
    ]);
});
```

In this case, you don't need to use two event handlers for the task and this `update` method (from QueryBuilder) won't fire any events.

Comment: This is causing more complexity than it's worth IMO.

Comment: This return only the id in slug, but is work without error

Comment: The previous one should work without any error but I've posted a much simpler solution. @Jessedc